# Is there an easy way to subtract a small dataframe from a large sorted one in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that was cleaned up and sorted, but unfortunately someone put some data in twice. Is there an easy way in R to, say, read the duplicate subset in as a dataframe and then subtract it from the large dataframe to get rid of the duplicates?

For clarification, some data do occur multiple times, so the mere presence of a duplicate line doesn't mean that the data was in the smaller dataset that was merged twice.

Comment: ... so there are some duplicate rows allowed... so you only want to remove the duplicate rows that are in some other data.frame?

Comment: Yes, for every row in the small dataframe, I want to find one instance of that row in the large dataframe and delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of a slow and horrible approach, but it will get the job done.

```
#Setting up data which has the A row 3 times, the B row twice, and the C row 3 times
whichLet <- c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C")
A <-data.frame(Dog=1,Bob=2,Cat=3)
B <-data.frame(Dog=2,Bob=1,Cat=3)
C <- data.frame(Dog=3,Bob=2,Cat=1)
someDuplicates <- do.call(rbind,sapply(whichLet,get,simplify=FALSE))
# Specifying to remove one of the A rows and one of the C rows, this is the same as
toRemove <- do.call(rbind,sapply(c("A","C"),get,simplify=FALSE))
# we now have the data frames you mentioned

while (nrow(toRemove) > 0) { #keep doing this until we've removed all the rows you specified
  uniqueDF <- unique(someDuplicates)
  duplicatedDF <- someDuplicates[duplicated(someDuplicates),]
  # removing the first row of toRemove from uniqueDF
  uniqueDF <- uniqueDF[!apply(apply(uniqueDF,1,function(x) {x==toRemove[1,]}),2,all),]
  # merging the unique back with the duplicates
  someDuplicates <- rbind(uniqueDF,duplicatedDF)
  # removing the item just removed from toRemove
  toRemove <- toRemove[-1,]
}
```

Note this can fail silently, e.g. if you remove a row that doesn't exist in uniqueDF it just keeps going because the unset of uniqueDF retained is everything.

Comment: Thanks very much. This will be helpful when I encounter this problem again. I just realised that my particular dataset has a quirk that allows me to take a shortcut: the small dataset rows are unique (not found in other subsets that were merged to form the big dataset). I hence exported to text, and in the bash shell did `grep -vFf small.txt big.txt > big2.txt; cat small.txt >> big2.txt; sort big2.txt > big.txt;`